# issue with makefile for including math.h

Tags: c, gcc

in my project I need to use the math.h lib. So in my makefile I added -lm to the file in question. 
Here is the line :

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c fourmi.c -lm -o fourmi.o
```

I compile with gcc and my CFLAGS has `-Wall -ansi -std=c99` 
I thought it would be correct but when I compile I am told :

```
undefined reference to pow/sqrt...
```

I know a lot of posts talk about this but none of those helped me.
Does anybody has a clue of what could possibly be wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The above command only create an object file.  What command create the executable?

Comment: `math.h` is a **header** for the math lib. The name of the lib depends on your platform and is required for linking. `-ansi` and `-std=c99` exclude each other. ANSI-C is not C99. Use the latter (better: standard C which would be C11), ANSI-C is outdated since 18 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please show the rest of your makefile. The `-lm` belongs elsewhere in your makefile.

Comment: Your link doesn't work (of course, it's a _local_ link that works only on _your_ computer). Please edit your question and post your make file _there_.

Comment: my executable command is : rendu1.x : error.o lecture.o fourmi.o \n gcc rendu1.o error.o fourmi.o lecture.o

Comment: You have to put `-lm` to the line where executable is linked.

Comment: List libraries after object files in link commands.  The command you show doesn't trigger the error you show.  A similar command for linking that lists `-lm` before `fourmi.o` on the command line might generate the error you show.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from you comment that you underestimated the intricacies of a `Makefile`.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
  printf("The third root of 5 is about: %.20g\n",pow(5.0,1/3.0));
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

A simple, although not *the* simplest, `Makefile` for it could be

```
# Just what I regularily use, YMMV, of course
CFLAGS += -O3 -g3  -W -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized -Wstrict-aliasing -std=c11
# Libmath
LIBS += -lm

# the executable is made from one or more object files
# if you have more, add them here
fourmi_executable: fourmi.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) fourmi.o  -o fourmi $(LIBS)
# an object file is made from one sourcecode file)
# if you have more, add more of these constructs
fourmi.o: fourmi.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c fourmi.c 

clean: 
    rm *.o 
    rm fourmi_executable
```

(Don't forget: the whitespace inserts are made by one tab, not spaces!)

This `Makefile` is very simple and not good for more than a handful of sourcefiles or anything more complicated than just compiling into one executable but should be useful as a start.

Comment: Is there an elegant way to prevent having to write 
my_exe: my_exe.o
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS) 
for all programs in my little project?

** found it!  you need to assign the libraries options to LDLIBS and not LIBS.

Comment: @rew Hu? Ah, that one. `LDLIBS` is for the linker `ld` which might not be the one you want/can use. My version is intentionally a general one. There is also a difference between GNU-makefiles (e.g.: Linux) with many GNU extensions and Unix-makfiles (e.g. BSD). If you want the GNU extensions you need to install  GNU-make (`gmake` in most BSDs).

Comment: I want a tool like "make" to help me. If I have to write out the complete command for every compile-step, then I can just as well write a shell script (bat file in DOS-speak). 
It is probably a personal preference, but I like the Makefile to be compact. And easy to expand. I have a few projects where I have a bunch of simple programs managed by that one Makefile. Then I very much prefer adding just the one extra program to BINS=... instead of having to add stuff like the linker line explicitly.